# Finding (older?) applications for an iPod Touch 4G device (IOS 6.1.6)

Tags: ipod-touch, compatibility, ipod.app

As a 4th generation iPod Touch user, I'm growing increasingly frustrated with the App Store; searching for applications turns up (thousands?) of results -- nearly all of which do not seem to support iOS 6.

Is there some trick to limiting search results to that which supports my hardware? Can I find older versions of applications that WOULD have worked on my iPod, back in 2012?

Answer (score 1):

I did a search in the App Store using the search criteria "iOS 6" and a bunch of apps came up. I checked a few, and the ones I checked all said they were compatible with iOS 6.0 and later. If there is a certain type of app you're looking for, I would imagine using the search criteria "iOS 6 music," for example, may bring up music apps compatible with iOS 6.0.

Comment: I attempted this, but many of the applications that I have found that support iOS 6 actually do not come up with these search criteria.